# matrices what is the meaning of defined?

Tags: matrices, definition

Please explain what is meant by "defined".
I have a MCQ type question that goes like this:

If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, $B$ is an $n \times p$ matrix and $C$ is a $p \times n$ matrix, then

a) $AB$ is defined for all $m$,$n$,$p$.
b) $A^TC$ is defined for all $m$,$n$,$p$.
c) $BC$ and $CB$ are both squre matrices.
d) $B^TC^T$ is of order $n \times n$.
e) none of above.

I know that the answer c) is correct and d) is wrong.
But I do not understand what is meant by answers a) and b). Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By "*defined*", it means that the resulting matrix exists. For example you should know that if you have matrix $A$ that is $2 \times 4$ and matrix $B$ that is $3 \times 5$, the product of these matrices $AB$ doesn't exists because the dimensions don't match. If this happens, we can say that $AB$ is "*not defined*".
The other product $BA$ is also "*not defined*" for the same reason. The matrix product $AB$ is only "*defined*" if the number of columns in $A$ is the same as the number of rows in $B$ (the dimensions match).